# Getting time zones that are at a particular hour using PHP

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I was wondering if there was a way to use PHP to generate a list of all current timezones that are at a particular hour?

*eg. all global locations with the current time of* `09:00`.

Would PHP automatically account for daylight savings also?

Anything I come across here or other sites are either countdowns or display every timezone. I only want the code to spit out those at the set hour and ignore others until it's said time there.

Comment: I would probably do something like this: 1. get the current time in UTC. Take the time I want , say `0930`, and subtract it from the current UTC time, this would give you the offset of the timezone in UTC (+/- some hhmm value), you could then pass this into offset into the `DateTimeZone` object and use `getName()` member

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this

1. Create a `DateTime` instance representing the current instant
2. Iterate over all the timezones PHP knows about
3. Filter the list for timezones who's current, formatted time matches your criteria

Something like this assuming you want all zones with the current *hour* being 9am (so any time between 09:00 and 09:59)

```
$now = new DateTime();
$searchHour = 9;
$zones = array_filter(DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(), function($tz) use ($now, $searchHour) {
    return $now->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($tz))->format('G') == $searchHour;
});
```

Demo ~ https://eval.in/889126

---

If you want to get a list of zone identifiers without their country / area prefix, try something like this...

```
$shortZones = array_map(function($tz) {
    // Turn "_" to " " and return the last part after "/"
    return str_replace('_', ' ', substr(strstr($tz, '/'), 1));
}, $zones);
```

Comment: Is there any way @Phil to strip off the zone and just have the city? Eg from "Pacific/Fiji" to "Fiji"...

Comment: @MichaelMarchment sure, but it wouldn't be a timezone then and some of the results would be confusing. I'll add an example anyway

Comment: @MichaelMarchment not sure what you'd want to do for zones like `America/North_Dakota/Center`

Comment: With jQuery: $('.locality li:contains("America/North_Dakota/Center")').text("Center"); :D